# Allocating memory buffer for use in MPI_Pack()

Tags: c, mpi

I'm going to use `MPI_Pack()` to make a message composed of n `int`s and m `double`s. Their positions in the message buffer will be something like this

p1 x `int`s, q1 x `double`s, p2 x `int`s, q2 x `double`s, ..., pN x `int`s, qN x `double`s

where n=p1+p2+...+pN and m=q1+q2+...+qN.

My question: Is the size of this message equal to the size of a message composed of the same number of `int`s and `double`s but with the following order:

n x `int`s, m x `double`s

I'm asking this question because I want to know how much memory should be allocated for the buffer. If the size of the message depends only on the number of `int`s and `double`s and not how they are arranged, then the buffer can be allocated very easily:

```
MPI_Pack_size(n, MPI_INT, communicator, &k1);
MPI_Pack_size(m, MPI_DOUBLE, communicator, &k2);
buffer = malloc(k1 + k2);
```

Obviously the following solution is correct:

```
k = 0;
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    MPI_Pack_size(p[i], MPI_INT, communicator, &k1);
    MPI_Pack_size(q[i], MPI_DOUBLE, communicator, &k2);
    k += k1 + k2;
}
buffer = malloc(k);
```

But for a large N, it may result in a too excessively large buffer, because as the official document of MPI states, the routine `MPI_Pack_size()`

> returns an upper bound, rather than an exact bound, since the
> exact amount of space needed to pack the message may depend on the context (e.g.,
> first message packed in a packing unit may take more space).

UPDATE: a program I wrote for testing if the order of packing the `int`s and `double`s affect the size of the message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 200000   /* buffer size in bytes */
#define MY_MPI_REAL MPI_DOUBLE

typedef double real;

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int ic = 0, rc = 0; /* counters of int and real numbers */
    int pos = 0;   /* position in the buffer, used in MPI_Pack() calls */

    /* allocate memory of the pack buffer */

    void *buff = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    assert(buff);

    /* case 1: packing a large number of pairs of arrays */

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)  /* 100 array pairs */
    {
        /* make int and real arrays of random lengths */
        int ik = 99 * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) + 1;
        int rk = 99 * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) + 1;
        int *iarr = (int *)malloc(ik * sizeof(int));
        assert(iarr);
        double *rarr = (real *)malloc(rk * sizeof(real));
        assert(rarr);

        ic += ik;
        rc += rk;

        /* pack the array pair */
        MPI_Pack(iarr, ik, MPI_INT, buff, BUFF_SIZE, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(rarr, rk, MY_MPI_REAL, buff, BUFF_SIZE, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        free(iarr);
        free(rarr);
    }

    printf("final position for case 1 = %d\n", pos);

    /* case 2: packing a single pair of arrays */

    pos = 0;

    int *iarr = (int *)malloc(ic * sizeof(int));
    assert(iarr);
    double *rarr = (real *)malloc(rc * sizeof(real));
    assert(rarr);

    MPI_Pack(iarr, ic, MPI_INT, buff, BUFF_SIZE, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Pack(rarr, rc, MY_MPI_REAL, buff, BUFF_SIZE, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    free(iarr);
    free(rarr);

    printf("final position for case 2 = %d\n", pos);

    free(buff);

    printf("sizeof(int) = %ld, sizeof(real) = %ld\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(real));
    printf("num of ints = %d, num of reals = %d\n", ic, rc);
    printf("num of ints x sizeof(int) + num of reals x sizeof(real) = %ld\n", ic*sizeof(int)+rc*sizeof(real));

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Before you worry about "excessive" memory demands, why don't you test it? My guess is that you may get a 1/3rd overhead: 4 byte int into 8 bytes, 8 byte real by itself. So 16 bytes for 12 bytes of data. Is my guess. Plus a couple of bytes incase your buffer is not aligned itself.

Comment: If you really worry about memory allocation, use a derived datatype so you do not have to allocate any intermediate buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your worries are misplaced. The only possible overhead I see would be from alignment: maybe a one time alignment at the start of the buffer, and then maybe per element. However, the pack buffer is counted in bytes, and I just tested it: even packing a single byte does not lead to any padding. So that leads me to suspect that every data type basically takes the exact amount of space.

Comment: Thank, but your answer is not clear enough to me. Particularly, I'm not sure what you mean by "your worries". I'd like to allocate memory for the buffer with the least possible calls to `MPI_Pack_size()`, because this function must take into account the size of the data needed for data conversion in heterogeneous environments.

Comment: I mean the data needed for data conversion is placed at the beginning of the pack buffer (only once), while `MPI_Pack_size()` counts it each time it is called. This is only what I guess; I don't know the exact mechanism of `MPI_Pack()`.

Comment: Your worries about "excessively large" buffers. On my machine `Pack_size` seems to give the exact size of each element, so there is no excess. Like I said before: test it.

Comment: Today I tested it with the program I added to the question and there is no excess on my laptop (to my surprise). I guess that the MPI implementation has detected that the program has been run on a shared memory system, so no conversion is needed. Unfortunately I have no access to a system with distributed memory at the moment.

Comment: While doing such tests can be helpful, some behaviors may depend on the machine type or the MPI implementation. The MPI document states that the implementation can "add at the head of packing units additional information, such as a description of the sender architecture (to be used for type conversion, in a
heterogeneous environment)."